# How to isolate the variable $c$ n this system of equations?

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

$$\begin{align}
5.5 &= a\cdot\sin(11\pi/24-c) + d \\
9   &= a\cdot\sin(2\pi/3-c) + d \\
\sin⁡(\pi/8)/2+15 &= a\cdot\sin(\pi/4-c) + d \\
\end{align}$$

Above is the system of equations in question.
Is it possible to isolate $c$? I want to construct a function that passes through these points but am finding difficulty in doing so.

It is possibly an issue of the function not being defined at these points?

Thanks.

Comment: 'It is possibly an issue of the function not being able to pass all of these points?' Perhaps you mean the function is not defined at 'these' points?

Answer (score 1):

I believe, the problem is something like this: Find values $a$, $c$, $d$ such that $f(x)=a \sin(x-c)+d$ passes through three given points $(x_i,y_i)$, $i=1,2,3$.

Using formula $\sin(x-c)=\sin x \cos c - \sin c \cos x$, substituting $a\cos c=p$, $a\sin c=q$, we can obtain following linear system for $p$, $q$, $d$: $$y_i=p\sin x_i-q\cos x_i+d.$$

Linear system may have no solution in definite cases. For points given in question, system will have unique solution.

$p=a\cos c$, $q=a\sin c$ $\Rightarrow$ $p^2+q^2=a^2$. There are two possible values of $a_{1,2}=\pm\sqrt{p^2+q^2}$ and two sets of $c=c_{1,2}+2k\pi$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, where $\cos c_i=\frac{p}{a_i}$, $\sin c_i=\frac{q}{a_i}$.

Answer (score 1):

So you have 3 determining equations for $a$, $c$ and $d$ of the form
$$\begin{align}y_n  &= a\cdot\sin(t_n - c)+d\quad\text{ with } n = 1,2,3 \tag 1\\
y &= (5.5,\ 9,\ \sin(\pi/8) + 15) \\
t &= (11/24,\ 2/3,\ 1/4)\cdot \pi
\end{align}$$

Subtracting $n=2,3$ from $n=1$ eliminates $d$ from $(1)$. And for shorter formulae, let's use notations like $y_{uv}=y_u-y_v$ for differences:

$$\begin{align}
y_{12}/a &= \sin (t_1-c) - \sin(t_2-c) \\
y_{13}/a &= \sin (t_1-c) - \sin(t_3-c) \\\tag 2
\end{align}$$

Dividing the two equations $(2)$ eliminates $a$:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{y_{12}}{y_{13}}
&= \frac{\sin (t_1-c) - \sin(t_2-c)}{\sin (t_1-c) - \sin(t_3-c)}\\
&= \frac{\sin x - \sin(t_{21}+x)}{\sin x - \sin(t_{31}+x)}\\
&= \frac{\sin x - \sin t_{21}\cos x- \cos t_{21}\sin x}{\sin x - \sin t_{31}\cos x- \cos t_{31}\sin x}\\
&= \frac{\tan x - \sin t_{21} - \cos t_{21}\tan x}{\tan x - \sin t_{31} - \cos t_{31}\tan x} \tag 3\\
\end{align}$$
with $x = t_1-c$. Now $(3)$ is just a linear equation in $\tan x$ of the form:
$$\begin{align}
Y &= \frac{S_2 - C_2\tan x}{S_3 - C_3\tan x} \\
(S_n,\ C_n,\ Y) &= (\sin t_{n1},\ 1-\cos t_{n1},\ y_{12}/y_{13})
\end{align}$$
so that you can work back from

$$\begin{align}
\tan x = \frac{S_2 - YS_3}{C_2-YC_3} \tag 4
\end{align}$$

to get:
$$\begin{align}
c \equiv t_1 - \arctan \frac
{y_{13}\sin t_{21} - y_{12}\sin t_{31}}
{y_{13}(1-\cos t_{21})-y_{12}(1-\cos t_{31})} \mod \pi \tag 5
\end{align}$$

You then get $a$ from $(2)$ and $d$ from $(1)$.

### **Notes on the solution**

- $c$ is only determined up to integer multiples of $\pi$.
- Solutions to $(1)$ are periodic in $c$ with period $2\pi$.
- Adding an odd multiple of $\pi$ to $c$ will just flip the sign of $a$.
- Any permutation of the indices will yield the same solution(s).  This can be handy if the denominator in $(4)$, $(5)$ is zero (and the numerator is not).
- Plugging all that stuff in a calculator yields:$$\begin{align}
  c &\approx 0.02960560 + k\pi\\
  a &\approx -32.80221277\cdot(-1)^k \\
  d &\approx 37.88059461 \\
  \end{align}$$